# High precision millisecond timer in matlab

Tags: matlab, timer, windows-10

I'm trying to implement a high-precision, millisecond-timescale timer in matlab. Every T seconds, I want to query a camera linked to matlab, and if there is an image in the memory, I want to pull it out. The actual connection to the camera is straightforward - but a problem arises because images are coming in every ~60ms, and need to all be pulled off before another image enters the camera buffer. This essentially means that I need to be checking the camera buffer at least every ~30ms, and ideally every ~5ms.

While MATLAB's built in `timer` function ostensibly allows millisecond timing, it suffers from poor precision. While in >95% of executions the built in MATLAB timer will indeed pause for ~5ms between runs, in ~5% of cases it hovers around ~30ms, and in ~1% of cases it takes >100ms between executions, which unacceptably kills the performance. I should clarify in MATLAB's defense that simultaneously there are two other timers running (both with 1 s periods), as well as a number of figure windows open, so even though my machine is beefy (16-core, 64GB RAM), there is certainly a lot to be doing all at once. I have tried using timers based on .NET timers (`System.Timers.Timer(period)`) as well as with the Java sleep function (`java.lang.Thread.sleep(period)`), both of which should theoretically be more precise, and while both are better than the MATLAB timer (at the cost of being more unwieldy), none are able to consistently achieve <60ms execution delay across thousands of iterations.

Maybe I'm asking for something which is not implementable - but I hope that there is some way to implement a high-precision timer in MATLAB which will continue executing at a ms time-scale even when there are other figures/timers/commands being executed semi-simultaneously. I should maybe clarify that when running just a timer with no other timers/figures open I am able to consistently achieve <60ms execution (and really, consistent <10ms execution for a 5ms timer period). This is possible even when all those timers/figures are open in a different instance of MATLAB, so it seems the problem is to somehow separate the timer from the rest of MATLAB. Any advice or guidance would be appreciated in this regard.

Comment: The only way to do that is to not run anything else on the computer. On Linux there is a real-time mode, were interrupts are disabled and one program gets to run exclusively, without interruptions. Maybe Windows has something similar. You cannot expect real-time performance in a multi-process environment.

Comment: Hi Cris, while I admit it is ostensibly difficult, the fact that the timer is able to run well with <10ms period when nothing else on MATLAB is open suggests to me that it isn't a problem of the operating system but with MATLAB's implementation of the timer protocol, which theoretically might have a fix.

Comment: I’m sure it runs well... until Java’s garbage collector kicks in, or the OS decides to index your files or look for updates, or some other scheduled job starts.

Comment: Yes, I admit OS level effects are a worry - but at least in my testing so far, I haven't ever run into an issue when running the timer on an instance of MATLAB with no other figures open/timers running. Perhaps those OS level effects will become problematic, but for now I'm trying to find a way to optimize the timer within MATLAB. I am running MATLAB on "High" priority which helps I'm sure.

Comment: I think you are encountering a typical MATLAB behavior. MATLAB program is not truly multi-threaded. If the program is busy (doing some work in a for loop for example), your timer callback is halted (unless you call `pause` or `drawnow`).

Comment: I think you need to consider a different architecture: Use [Image Acquisition Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/image-acquisition.html) if you can. If you can't, then implement an external DLL that grabs the images (empty the camera buffer), and allows queuing (buffering) multiple images. Your MATLAB program then reads the images from the DLL's buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you are doing, the timing system of [Psychtoolbox](http://psychtoolbox.org/) may help you.

Specifically, check out the [`WaitSecs`](https://github.com/Psychtoolbox-3/Psychtoolbox-3/blob/master/Psychtoolbox/PsychBasic/WaitSecs.m) function and its documentation. It is supposed to be more precise than `timer`, and the documentation contains some tips about achieving high precision timing in general.

Also related is the [`GetSecs`](https://github.com/Psychtoolbox-3/Psychtoolbox-3/blob/master/Psychtoolbox/PsychBasic/GetSecs.m) function.

It might however happen that switching to `WaitSecs` will not help you. In that case you can be quite sure that your machine is just too loaded to do what you are trying to do.